# Invoke an API using python with arguments

Tags: python, api, invoke

i want to invoke an API by passing arguments , since am first to this am having some problem which am not able to figure it out .

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://URLVALUE'
head = {'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8','SOAPAction': 'POST'}
param ={'user':'KOKO',
            'TMUserPwd':'ADMIN',
            'data':'getUserProfile.xml',
            'output':'getOut.out'}

parame= json.dumps(param)
ret = requests.post(url,headers=head,data=parame)
ret.status_code
```

So i want to pass a file (.xml) which will be passed as a param during invoking including USERNAME , PASSWORD etc . and retrieve the result in the form of .out file .

now it is not showing me any error but it doesn't connect nor create any file with getOut.out name

Comment: Your endpoint (i.e. `https://urlValue` for sample code) returns a [HTTP 500](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500). You should focus on the serving side.

Comment: am literally new to this , and i just didn't get what you said now , if you explain me a little it would be a great help @vahdet

Comment: i edited code a little , now it is not showing me any error , but it doesn't connect or retrieve getOut.out file  @vahdet